# MySQL or MSSQL as backend for Access database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ms-access

A client wants me to migrate his (very big) Microsoft Access database to a SQL server, keeping Access as the frontend. They have many users already and performance issues are getting worse.

Now, which SQL server would be most appropriate?

`MySql`: I have many years experience with MySQL and consider myself an expert, although not in connection with Access. Being free, MySQL is also attractive to my client.

`MSSQL`: I was once very experienced with MSSQL but it was 12 years ago or more. Much has happened since. But being a Microsoft product, I figure that data migration to the SQL server and use with Access in general might be somewhat more streamlined, which could perhaps compensate for the lack of (recent) experience with the product.

So, how is it working with MySQL as a backend for Access as opposed to MSSQL? Should I count on major obstacles that would work increase the time needed for the migration considerably or would my great experience with MySQL more than compensate for such obstacles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cost is a major concern, there are free versions of SQL server that will probably be more than capable of handling any database migrated from Access. (ie: [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) )

Integration between Access and SQL Server is indeed more streamlined, and as long as you don't have too many MySQL bad habits (eg: omitting group by elements), then your lack of recent experience shouldn't make much difference for the likely level of SQL required for this project.

Comment: Depends how big is the Access DB -- if the whole solution has 10 linked tables of 2 GB each, SQL Server Standard Edition might be required (Express has a limit of 10 GB DB size).

Comment: @mceda That's a good point, however don't assume 2GB in Access represents 2GB in MS SQL as the compression methods in MS SQL are likely more advanced than those of Access.

Comment: I can't really see why this question is not a good fit for Stackoverflow. Anyway, your answer is fine for me and I think I will go for SQL Server Express. Thanks.